# Outputting to a text file in lisp

Tags: file, io, lisp

I am new to LISP, and I am having trouble in writing a text file. I have read through the cookbook and other tutorials, as well as the following examples here, but I keep getting the same error:

```
"Incorrect keyword arguments in (:DIRECTION
                                :OUTPUT
                                :IF-EXSISTS
                                :SUPERCEDE
                                :IF-DOES-NOT-EXSIST
                                :CREATE) .
   [Condition of type CCL::SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]"
```

my code is as follows:

```
(defun writeTest()
       (with-open-file (str "numbers.txt"
       :direction :output 
       :if-exsists :supercede 
       :if-does-not-exsist :create)

       (format str "printing to a file")))
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong spelling: `"exsists"` --> `"exists"`.

Comment: Well this just might be the stupidest mistake I have made in programming, thanks for pointing that out haha.

Comment: Also, `:supercede` should be `:supersede`